# Stuck with SQL Update statement, possible Inner Join (Unsure)?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, inner-join

I have a MS Access table with 3 columns named `Code`, `[Money Amt]`, and `Line` in a table named `Actual Debt`.

[image]

I am trying to write an SQL statement that will help me automate this process. I want the statement to look for rows with identical values in their code columns. Then look at the `[Money Amt]` and locate pairs that have the reverse values (In this case the pair would be `200`, and `-200`). When it finds the pair of rows with the same `Code` value and reverse `[Money Amt]` it will then populate the `Line` column value with `999`.

In this case the second and fourth row would be selected as the pair and have the resulting line value of `999`.

I know that this will probably require an `INNER JOIN`. I haven't gotten very far besides this, I don't know how to structure the `INNER JOIN` due to being a newbie.

```
UPDATE [Actual Debt] SET Line = 999;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UPDATE from SELECT using SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server)

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38329845/sql-in-ms-access-trouble-with-inner-join/38330336#38330336.  You should reword your original question as it's on hold - this has just added some formatting.  For what it's worth - I'm not sure why it was put on hold in the first place, but my response to your original question answered it (so I thought).

Comment: `UPDATE  [Actual Debt] T3 INNER JOIN [Actual Debt] T4 ON T3.[Money Amt] = -T4.[Money Amt] AND T3.Code <> T4.Code
SET     T3.Line = 999` - from original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on track.  Here is one way:

```
update [Actual Debt]
    set line = 999
    where exists (select 1
                  from [Actual Debt] as ad2
                  where ad2.code = [Actual Debt].code and
                        ad2.[Money Amt] = - [Actual Debt].[Money Amt]
                 );
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly, and I now understand it better. Thank you!

Comment: Actually now that I analyze the database further I am noticing that there a few instances where there are 3 lines with the 999 code that have the same code and [Money Amt]. There should only be pairs, so their should be a 1:1 ratio with a code that has an opposing money amt of the same code. I can tell it would have to do with the subquery, but I'm not sure how to tell it to do pairs only.  Is there a way to fix this? Sorry if this is confusing

Comment: @Mccormack . . . Can you ask another question with appropriate sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about MS Access syntax, but this is the general idea.

```
update t1
set line = 999
from [actual debt] t1 join [actual debt] t2 on t1.code = t2.code
and t1.[money amt] = t2.[money amt] * -1
```

Comment: I recognize this syntax as SQL Server syntax, but not MS Access syntax.